# How can I take string input character by character without return key?

Tags: c, string

I need to enter a very long string for which I don't need to reserve any memory (no need to read the string later, just once character by character). How can I process the string without receiving the complete string? 
This is my code snippet:

```
for(length = n; length > 0; length--) {
    input = getchar();
    if (input == ...
        ...
```

Obviously this doesn't work but it makes my intentions clear. How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: To me, your intentions aren't clear. What do you mean by “without return key”? And where does `n` come from?

Comment: +1 Good Question. Still need clarification, How should one recognize `end of string`?

Comment: This is only part of code. n is the length of the string input earlier. the input is a long string but I don't want to store the whole string in memory before processing it. iow, no char array or malloc.

there is a '\n' in the end of string.

Comment: How do you know the length of a string the user is going to enter?

Comment: like I said, "earlier" in the code, I asked the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it correctly then you may try like this:

```
while (1)
{
        char c = (char)getchar();
        if(c=='\n')
        break;
        // do your logic here
}
```

Comment: This is an infinite loop, if the input doesn't end in a newline or on a read error…

Comment: @mafso:- Yes I am aware of that but this is what I thought what OP wants since he wants to enter the characters one by one without break!

Comment: this example code has the problem that getchar returns an int, so certain return values, like '\n' in DOS/Windows (two chars together) and EOF can be properly input.  Forcing the input to an 8 bit char looses the ability to recognize a '\n' and EOF.

Answer (score 0):

Below logic will helps you

```
for(length = n; length > 0; length--) 
{
    input = getchar();
    if (input is required values)
    {
        process it
    }
    else if (input is end of input indicator)
    {
        break;
    }
    else //unwanted characters
    {
        continue; //skip it
    }   
}
```